# Where the log stream goes?

Tags: java, operating-system

when an app is started, not from the console but from an UI icon, where the standard stream goes, I mean can I for example see this log? Where the plain old System.out directs to as a "default" ?

Comment: All log streams lead to the log sea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Angus said, without a console you don't get output.

Once you've launched your application as a GUI, you can set the `System.out` field to log to another destination (rather than a TTY or a console), by using [System.setOut](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29). In that way you can write to a file by passing:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(path_to_a_file));
```

However, this is not advised.

The best thing you can do is to use a logging framework such as log4j or SLF4J, and perform logging (to a file, network host or console) that way.

Comment: +1: If you don't control it, you have no idea where it ends.  In our production environment System.out is buffered.  Hence, we cannot be certain to be able to see the latest thing printed (yet) which is rather tedious when trying to see what happens.  That's when we decided to fix the logging configuration so all was sent to files.

Answer (score 0):

If the app doesn't have a console then generally standard output doesn't go anywhere.